# Out-of-bag estimate biased by correlated features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, deep-learning

I have a data set with a small number of samples (322) and a large number of features (318.976). My data consists of images, and I want to train a binary classifier.

Since I have such a small amount of data available, I have employed the following strategy:

- Reduce dimensionality using a few hand-written rules (from 318.976 to 12.000 features)
- Train Sparse Filter to reduce dimensionality further (from 12.000 to 1000 features

  - To train the sparse filter, I construct additional data by shifting my images horizontally which my problem is invariant under. This gives me 19.320 samples instead of 322.
- Now my data set has 19.320 samples and 1000 features
- In the training set, only around 2% of the samples are positives
- Now I train a random forest on the data set weighting the positive samples up so they in total achieves the same weight as the negative samples

Here my problem arises. I get a quite good OOB-estimate from my random forest, but it is overly confident. The problem is that when I shifted my data to obtain more samples and then trained the sparse filter, I get some some sets of features which are just shifted versions of each other. When I then train my random forest, these features have a very high correlation, and the OOB-estimate does not take into account that some of my features are very highly correlated, consequently over-estimating the predictive power.

Since I have so few samples originally, I have no good way to do cross-validation, especially since I have a highly imbalanced data set. Is there any way to get slightly more accurate error-estimates?